# VBA Interior.Color based on another row cell color

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help with simple vba macro.

I've got this sheet with 3 rows **A**, **H**, **I**

Cells in **A** are filled with some values and colored.
Cells in **H** may be filled with similar values and not colored.
Cells in **I** contain some numeric data.

Overall idea for macro is to match values from **A** and **H**, if **H** has exact value from **A**, then it's filled with the **A** cell color. This part is working fine for me.

Next step is to color cells in **I** accordingly to **H**, just based on it's position relative to **H**. For example **I54** must be colored same as **H54**.

I tried adding another for cycle for **I** row, and plain `range("I3:I100").interior.color =  range("H3:H100").interior.color` but it seems I don't quite understand vba or programming...

Here's my current script

```
Sub test()
Dim acel As Range
Dim hcel As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    For Each acel In .Range("A3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        For Each hcel In .Range("H3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp))
            If hcel.Value = acel.Value Then
                hcel.Interior.Color = acel.Interior.Color
                
            End If
        Next hcel
    Next acel
            

End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the color for each cell, not all cells at once:

```
For Each acel In .Range("H3:H100")
    acel.Offset(0, 1).Interior.Color = acel.Interior.Color
Next acel
```